# Check if the current date is passed then do something using a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Bootstrap grids (with no datepicker) and I would like to highlight a grid that has a passed date value in it.  I found a quick and dirty way but I'm pretty sure there is a better solution to clean this up. Maybe by looping through the grids in the .dates column. I tried to use `<time>` with datetime attribute but I'm not sure if that helps and how to get those dates and compare them in a loop.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container important-dates">
      <div class="row h-100">
          <div class="col-sm-5 my-auto impo">
            <h3><span>Important</span> Dates</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-7 dates">
            <div class="row early-action">
                <div class="col-sm-5 date-label first">
                  <time datetime="2021-6-2">June 2</time>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7 date-action">
                  <h4>Early Action</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row early-decision">
                <div class="col-sm-5 date-label">
                  <time datetime="2021-7-10">July 10</time>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7 date-action">
                  <h4>Early Decision</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row regular-action">
                <div class="col-sm-5 date-label">
                  <time datetime="2021-9-2">Sept 2</time>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7 date-action">
                  <h4>Regular Decision</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row open-house">
                <div class="col-sm-5 date-label">
                  <time datetime="2021-9-2">Oct 10</time>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7 date-action">
                  <h4>Open House</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

And this is my JS:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var earlyAction = new Date();
var earlyDecision = new Date();
var regularDecision = new Date();
var openHouse = new Date();
earlyAction.setFullYear(2021, 5, 2);
earlyDecision.setFullYear(2021, 6, 10);
regularDecision.setFullYear(2021, 8, 2);
openHouse.setFullYear(2021, 9, 10);
// check if dates are passed
if (currentDate.getTime() > earlyAction.getTime()) {
  $('.early-action').addClass('date-has-passed');
}
if (currentDate.getTime() > earlyDecision.getTime()) {
  $('.early-decision').addClass('date-has-passed');
}
if (currentDate.getTime() > regularDecision.getTime()) {
  $('.regular-decision').addClass('date-has-passed');
}
if (currentDate.getTime() > openHouse.getTime()) {
  $('.open-house').addClass('date-has-passed');
}
```

It is working fine but is there a way to make this shorter and cleaner? Preferably with jQuery.  [Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5osm1ng7/).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to work with data instead of the DOM?

Comment: It’s a static site, or did you mean data attributes? But even data attribute is working with the DOM, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` to iterate through your `time` element and then get the attribute of it i.e : *datatime* then compare this with *currentDate* if less then add your class.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
//loop through time elemnt
$(".important-dates time").each(function() {
  var data_time = new Date($(this).attr("datetime")) //get data-attr
  //compare
  if (data_time < currentDate) {
    $(this).closest(".row").addClass("date-has-passed")//add class
  }
})
```

```css
.date-has-passed {
  color: gray
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container important-dates">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-sm-5 my-auto impo">
      <h3><span>Important</span> Dates</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 dates">
      <div class="row early-action">
        <div class="col-sm-5 date-label first">
          <time datetime="2021-5-10">May 10</time>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7 date-action">
          <h4>Early Action</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row early-decision">
        <div class="col-sm-5 date-label">
          <time datetime="2021-6-10">June 10</time>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7 date-action">
          <h4>Early Decision</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row regular-action">
        <div class="col-sm-5 date-label">
          <time datetime="2021-9-2">Sept 2</time>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7 date-action">
          <h4>Regular Decision</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row open-house">
        <div class="col-sm-5 date-label">
          <time datetime="2021-10-2">Oct 2</time>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7 date-action">
          <h4>Open House</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the dates directly in the new date, and get time in the same line, and use operator `&&` for comparation, example:

```js
var currentDate = new Date().getTime();
var earlyAction = new Date(2021, 5, 2).getTime();
var earlyDecision = new Date(2021, 6, 10).getTime();
var regularDecision = new Date(2021, 8, 2).getTime();
var openHouse = new Date(2021, 9, 10).getTime();

var date_has_passed = 'date-has-passed';

// check if dates are passed
$('.early-action').addClass(currentDate > earlyAction && date_has_passed );
$('.early-decision').addClass(currentDate > earlyDecision && date_has_passed);
$('.regular-decision').addClass(currentDate > regularDecision && date_has_passed);
$('.open-house').addClass(currentDate > openHouse && date-has-passed);
```

```css
.date-has-passed {
color: green;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container important-dates">
          <div class="row h-100">
              <div class="col-sm-5 my-auto impo">
                <h3><span>Important</span> Dates</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-7 dates">
                <div class="row early-action">
                    <div class="col-sm-5 date-label first">
                      <time datetime="2021-6-2">June 2</time>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7 date-action">
                      <h4>Early Action</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row early-decision">
                    <div class="col-sm-5 date-label">
                      <time datetime="2021-7-10">July 10</time>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7 date-action">
                      <h4>Early Decision</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row regular-action">
                    <div class="col-sm-5 date-label">
                      <time datetime="2021-9-2">Sept 2</time>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7 date-action">
                      <h4>Regular Decision</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row open-house">
                    <div class="col-sm-5 date-label">
                      <time datetime="2021-9-2">Oct 10</time>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7 date-action">
                      <h4>Open House</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: This works too but I was looking for a loop solution, but thank you for the time. It's still a lot cleaner than my version.